# php save value in cURL response

Tags: php, curl

I made a cURL to Salesforce and got a responce like:

```
{"access_token":"XXXXXXXXX","instance_url":"https://na25.salesforce.com","id":"XXXXXXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","issued_at":"1458059021745","signature":"XXXXXXXX="}
```

I am trying to save the "access_token" like so but not working:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch2);
$session_id = $result['access_token'];
```

I have also tried:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch2);
$parsed = array();
parse_str($result, $parsed);
$session_id = $parsed['access_token'];
```

Comment: You are looking for [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php): `$json_decode = json_decode($result); $session_id = $json->access_token;`

Comment: try with `$result_aray = json_decode($result); $session_id = $result_aray ['access_token'];`

Comment: `parse_str()` is for ripping apart a query string, e.g. `foo=bar&baz=qux`. you don't have a query string, you have json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the API is returning a json string. you need to run it through [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) first.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch2);

$resultArray = json_decode($result, true);

$session_id = $resultArray['access_token'];
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try with below code

```
$result = curl_exec($ch2);
$result_aray = json_decode($result,true);
$session_id = $result_aray ['access_token'];
```

Let me know still anything.